# how to retrive data as list in django database

Tags: python, html, django, database, jinja2

I am trying to get a list of questions that i have stored in database in django.While retriving i am getting  a list of quetions queryset something like below on browser

#### Output

```
<QuerySet [<Question: what is your name ?>, <Question: what is sky color ?>, <Question: which mobile used ?>]>
```

needed output only questions

## My Code:

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice1=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    choice2=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    choice4 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**html page**

```
<div>
  {{q}}
<div>
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import GeeksModel, Question,Choice

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(GeeksModel)
#admin.site.register(Choice)

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 0


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),

    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

**views.py**

```
def Quetionpaper(request,id):
    # dictionary for initial data with
    # field names as keys
    # add the dictionary during initialization

    q=Question.objects.all()[0:3]

    c=Choice.objects.all()


    context = {'q':q,'c':c}

    return render(request, "list_view.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

your template needs to look like this:

```
{% for element in q %}
    <div>
      {{element.question}}
    <div>
{% endfor %}
```